# trying to use vue CSS Transitions

Tags: npm, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

the doc has been poorly written here. I don't know at what stage it says to install something extra but from what I read there is nothing extra to install.

"Just place a `<transition>` tag in your vue, you'll see, it'll work" says the doc :
[image]

the button does nothing on click.

what could I be missing?

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

try it you can literally copy-paste their code (all three parts) it doesn't work.

UPDATE:

So I as told by I craig_h I indeed don't have my data's showing up.

here's my code :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import router from './router'
import Header from './components/header/Header.vue'
import LateralMenu from './components/lateralmenu/LateralMenu.vue'
import Example from './components/example.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('Header', Header)
Vue.component('LateralMenu', LateralMenu)
Vue.component('Example', Example)
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#nav',
  template: '<Header/>'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#lateral-menu',
  template: '<LateralMenu/>',
  data: {
    reveal: true,
    show: true
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  template: '<Example/>',
  data: {
    show: true
  }
})
```

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/t98oqhbs/

Comment: @craig_h everywhere but inside a vue-cli scaffold

Comment: @tatsu it works fine inside a scaffolded project.  Do your dev tools show any errors?  Is the paragraph tag hiding and showing without transitions?

Comment: @craig_h no it just doesn't do the reveal : https://i.imgur.com/0IgBBPm.gifv

Comment: vue.esm.js?efeb:571 [Vue warn]: Property or method "show" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Example> at src\components\example.vue
       <Root>

Comment: @tatsu that error means that you haven't added `show` to your `data()` property. Could you post the code for your component (by editing your question) so we can take a look at it?

Comment: it is indeed not showing up in vue devtools and the error message in browser console is specific to that yet I feel I've added the show to data as I should.

Comment: @tatsu you should consider using components instead of multiple Vue instances if you're already using a vue-cli scaffolded project.  Look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/m5v0xx5vq9) working example of a scaffolded project with a component and transition.  App.vue is where you want to look.

Comment: My bad I thought what I was doing *was* components. this is poorly explained in the docs.

Comment: Yeah in the guide the show single component setup whereas noone does that in real life. they should show a component-based example instead. now by having my variable declared in the `<script>` tag of my component it works just fine. you can go ahead and answer this @lamelemon and I'll mark you as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue doesn't come with out-of-the-box animations, so you have to add them to your css. This is the one they provide on they website.

Note how the naming of the animation corresponds to the name within the view component.

```
/* Enter and leave animations can use different */
/* durations and timing functions.              */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah i've added that to my Css. as I said in the OP I added *all three bits* of proposed code in the guide but to no avail.

Comment: have you tried it inside a vue-cli scaffolding? it does not work for me.